# What hd graphics really are

Tags: android, graphics

I am working on android app. I see lot of apps say they have hd graphics and i can see some difference in their graphics and mine. I searched on google also but cannot get exact answer as to what actually hd graphics means? Is it some kind of format like .png or is it resolution like 400*800. I mean if i want to make hd image of a simple button how can i do that? Can anyone please explain in deatail keeping android apps in mind. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really mean hd or do you mean hdpi?

Comment: @MisterSquonk - not sure what hdpi is but i have seen in few app written: this app has hd graphics.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need to check out the definition of HD. That stands for High Definition and it's main idea is that by making resolution big, on bigger screens the quality of an image or a video won't look bad.

About Buttons, in Android or any other OS most of the times vector graphics are used instead of bitmaps. Vector graphics are just some coordinates which make up graphic, so when you zoom in or display a vector graphic on a big screen it won't lose it's quality. Bitmaps are collections of pixels. Check this out to get a basic understanding of dpi and pixels: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch
In order to use bitmaps efficiently for buttons and that kind of controls I'd suggest taking a look at this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html

Comment: This thread will also help you to make a better contrast between the two: http://www.graphicdesignforum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=41